# Coyoneda and Deriving Functor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

After studying the category theory based on MacLane, Awodey and Spivak books, I'm trying to understand free/operational monad in Haskell.

We can get a monad from just a data type by using `Control.Monad.Free` after transforming it to a functor with `Data.Functor.Coyoneda`, which is based on the mathematical background called Yoneda lemma.

But I'm not fully understanding the functor can be automatically generated by the deriving functor extension in GHC instead of relying on Yoneda lemma.

Is there any restriction to use the deriving functor in GHC compared to `Data.Functor.Coyoneda`?

Comment: maybe you'll find [this blogpost](https://oleksandrmanzyuk.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/co-yoneda-lemma/) helpful

Answer (score 8):

Good question!

`Coyoneda` and `DeriveFunctor` do different things. `Coyoneda` creates a new, separate datatype which happens to be a `Functor` for any choice of argument. `DeriveFunctor` simply generates the boilerplate code for types which *are* functors by themselves. You can only derive a `Functor` instance for types for which you could write such an instance by hand.

Take `newtype Pred a = Pred (a -> Bool)` as a (somewhat contrived) example: there is no `instance Functor Pred` because `Pred` is contravariant in its `a` parameter, so`DeriveFunctor` won't be able to help you. On the other hand `Coyoneda Pred` is a `Functor` because `Coyoneda f` is a `Functor`, albeit not a very useful one, for any `f`.

As an aside, the [Freer monad](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf) arises as an application of `Free` to `Coyoneda`.

Comment: Is `Coyoneda Pred` nearly isomorphic or equivalent in some sense to `Const ()`? You shouldn't be able to extract any information from any of them...

Comment: @chi Yeah, I suppose so. You can manufacture a `Coyoneda Pred` from nothing by picking `Void` as the existentially quantified `b` type inside it: `Coyoneda absurd absurd :: forall a. Coyoneda Pred a`. Then it should be trivial to construct both directions of the isomorphism.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson if using the `DeriveFunctor` together with `StandaloneDeriving`, a typical datatype seem to be able to become a functor without benefiting from the power of `Coyoneda`, right?  I know the name of the Freer Monad but not fully understanding yet.

Comment: @sato Only if the datatype is already a (covariant) `Functor` to start with. `DerivingFunctor` only writes the boilerplate code that you would have written yourself.